# Case Statement Usage With Bind Variables

Tags: sql, oracle, case

I have a column called `purchase_order_status` in `purchases` table which contains `Open` and `Closed` as values.

```
SELECT *
  FROM purchases
 WHERE purchase_order_status = :status
```

If user passes `All` as bind parameter, how can I fetch all rows having `Open` and `Closed` status like the following using case statement?

```
in ('Open','Closed')
```

Is it possible to use bind variable in case statement, some thing like

```
case when :status = 'All' then 'Open','Closed'
```

Comment: I may be wrong, but why use a condition if all records will match it ?

Comment: you can only use CASE in the select clause

Comment: @Bartdude It is a good question, user can pass All,Open or Closed, so if it is All, then I have to use Open and Closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `case` but it's easier and clearer to just use normal logical operators:

```
SELECT *
  FROM purchases
 WHERE ((:status = 'All' AND purchase_order_status IN ('Open','Closed'))
    OR purchase_order_status = :status)
```

With some trivial sample data and an SQL*Plus bind variable:

```
create table purchases (purchase_order_status varchar2(10));

insert into purchases values ('Open');
insert into purchases values ('Closed');
insert into purchases values ('Pending');

var status varchar2(10);
```

Passing 'Open':

```
exec :status := 'Open';

anonymous block completed

SELECT *
  FROM purchases
 WHERE ((:status = 'All' AND purchase_order_status IN ('Open','Closed'))
    OR purchase_order_status = :status);

PURCHASE_ORDER_STATUS
---------------------
Open
```

And passing 'All:

```
exec :status := 'All';

anonymous block completed

SELECT *
  FROM purchases
 WHERE ((:status = 'All' AND purchase_order_status IN ('Open','Closed'))
    OR purchase_order_status = :status);

PURCHASE_ORDER_STATUS
---------------------
Open                  
Closed
```

If you can guarantee that the column can *only* hold those two values then you can simplify it further to just:

```
SELECT *
  FROM purchases
 WHERE :status = 'All' OR purchase_order_status = :status;
```

Comment: Alex +1, this is what I was looking for. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alex answer is better IMO, but here is an alternative.

```
declare @test as varchar(10)
set @test = 'ALL'
if(@test='ALL') begin
select * from purchases where purchase_order_status in('Open','Closed')
end
if(@test='OPEN') begin
select * from purchases where purchase_order_status in('Open')
end
```

Personally I would do this kind of thing in the code that generates the select queries (if there is such a code)

Comment: Dave I am using Oracle.

Comment: @Polppan - having separate queries might still make things even clearer and perhaps simpler for the parser too, but that may not be an option for you.